# String extract using or on dataframes

Tags: python

I am trying to clean up a dataframe so that I can `merge` on another dataframe, however, the `str.extract` isn't functioning as I intended.

This is my code

```
df['new column'] = df['column'].str.extract(r'(\d{11})(?=[A-Za-z]{2})|(\d{11})$')
```

Comment: You need to provide a sample of your input, what your code currently does and the expected output

Comment: What is your input file and what are you trying to remove? Without knowing what your input is and what you are trying to do, we don't think we can comment on your code. Someone may still be intuitive and figure out. I am not able to